# D4 error motherboard code "PCI resource allocation error. Out of Resources" with Nvidia M40 24 GB

Tags: pci-express, pci, nvidia

I try to put an Nvidia M40 with 24 GB of ram into my PC and it get that error:

```
...
PCI resource allocation error. Out of Resources
...
```

On the moderboard I can see D4.

My components:

- Motherboard: Asus Rog Maximus X Hero
- CPU: Intel 8086k
- Corsair 850W

I connect the M40 with the CPU 8x cable like I can read into [the manual](https://images.novatech.co.uk/website2017/DeepLearning/assets/datasheets/teslam40.pdf). I also try to remove the m2 because maybe it use PCI address but nothing. What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution, you must change in the Bios:

- Above 4G decoding : Enable
- CSM support : Enable
- Fast Boot : Disable

Save and reboot! With pop OS with Nvidia Driver it see all with `nvidia-smi` command, it works!

Comment: Pretty sure CSM isn’t required here. Only the first option should really matter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).